# Do we need to specify unique() in validation rule once we have already done it in migration file?

Tags: php, laravel

I have already specified a column to be unique in my migration file. Do I need to do it again in validation rule?

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('imageName')->unique();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a validation rule to get the error message, otherwise, whenever you will be adding two files with the same name it'll throw an exception ...